# Why is my IF ELSE statement defaulting backwards?

Tags: java, if-statement, javafx

I am very confused as to why this is happening. When I run this code and leave the txtFirstName field blank, it returns true even though it clearly shouldn't.

```
@FXML
private void signUp(ActionEvent event) {

    if (txtFirstName.getText() != null) {

        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setTitle("IT WORKS");
        alert.setHeaderText("IT WORKS!");
        alert.setContentText("IT WORKS!!!!!");
        alert.showAndWait();

    } else {

        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.WARNING);
        alert.setTitle("Warning");
        alert.setHeaderText("There was a problem creating your account");
        alert.setContentText("Please fill out every field with the minimum requirements!");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }

}
```

When I do type a value into the First Name field, I get the else statement when I should be getting the if statement... Am I insane or is this backwards?

Comment: Compare with `null` and `isEmpty()`? So `txtFirstName.getText() != null && !txtFirstName.isEmpty()` for instance?

Comment: It told me "the type .isEmpty() is undefined for the type TextField".

Comment: Ah, yes, `txtFirstName.getText().isEmpty()`

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes That's it! I did not compare it. just used `txtFirstName.getText().isEmpty()` by itself in the if statement and it worked exactly right. I'll need to keep that in mind for future use. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your First Name field is a String, you can use

`txtFirstName.getText().isEmpty();`

Hope this solves your question!

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isEmpty-java.lang.CharSequence-

Or write your own check that string is not null and has some characters.

You can also checkout StringUtils#isBlank